Angular. Pdfjs-dist worker. Problem in deployed production enviroment
I need to use pdf library pdfjs-dist. I set up worker like this:
PDF.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.mjs';

and in angular.json like this:
{
    "glob": "pdf.worker.*",
    "input": "node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/",
    "output": ""
},
{
    "glob": "pdf.*",
    "input": "node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/",
    "output": ""
}

The problem is that everything works locally but when the app is deployed setting up the worker fails and the file is blocked because of disallowed MIME „application/octet-stream".
Update: I managed to get it working by copying the worker.min.js file into assets. And changing this:
PDF.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '/assets/pdf.worker.mjs';

So I have another question. Is worker not included into bundle and that is why the problem is occuring? If so what is the appropriate solution.
How can I make it work without copying the worker file into assets folder?

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Also, rather than leaving a record of revisions to your question (before anyone has responded), just revise your question to update it as new. Otherwise you just confuse new readers.
